# How can you query other user profiles using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get

I'm experimenting with getting user data from the Facebook Graph API, but so far I can only retrieve information from my own profile. Using the Graph API Explorer, I'm sending GET requests for this information:

```
me?fields=id,name,birthday,picture,email
```

How can I change this to search for other users instead of "me"? For example, I want to search for profiles of people named "John Smith" and return pictures and birthdays for each profile of this name.

Comment: You can't. There is no API for that

Comment: @WizKid so there's no way to find user ids by searching names?

Comment: There is no way to get birthday and email from users that have not granted permission to your app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Search API to search for users by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

...but there is no way to get birthdays and emails of users if they did not authorize your App. You would not be allowed to use the emails anyway, even if you would get them.

Comment: Can you give an example of a name search and the JSON it returns? I've read though this doc and still can't make a Postman GET request work with this format:
    GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q={your-query}&
    type={object-type}

Comment: The documentation also say you need a user access token

Comment: exactly, all you need is a user token, the type "user" and a query.